# Set-builder notation for the "divides" relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to define the set for all pairs that are in the "divides" relation (e.g. a divides b).

$a$ is said to "divide" $b$ if there exists an $x$ such that $ax = b$. Is the following set-builder notation correct?

$$D(a,b)=\{(a,b) ∈ ℕ:∃x ∈ ℕ (ax=b)\}$$

I also want to know about any notational conventions so that I can make my definition maximally appropriate.

Comment: I think you mean $\exists c\in\mathbb N\;ac=b$. If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: In more pedantic company, some may complain that $(a,b)$ isn't itself and element of $\Bbb N$. You may wish to state more explicitly that either $a,b \in \Bbb N$ on the right or $(a,b) \in \Bbb N^2$ on the left.

Comment: @Brian I wouldn't really say that's pedantic - *in this case* it's clear what's meant, but in other situations keeping track of exactly what the "type" of an object is can be nontrivial, and it's good to learn to avoid this bad habit early on.

Comment: @DonThousand Fixed in edit. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian If I were in pedantic company, how would I include $a,b ∈ ℕ$ on the right-hand side?

$D(a,b) = \{(a,b): a,b ∈ ℕ,∃c ∈ ℕ(ac=b)\}$ ?

Comment: @Timo That would be acceptable

Comment: Or does this work (I think it seems more concise)?

$D(a,b) = \{(a,b): a,b,c ∈ ℕ, ∃c (ac=b)\}$

Comment: @DonThousand: The former is not valid since it contains a free variable (that is $c$).

Comment: Thanks, @DonThousand! (I would mark your comment as usefwl if the option appeared to be.)